# How to let Ansible to skip run tasks on a host when its already configured?

Tags: ansible

We have 2 playbooks `Basic-env` and `Upgrade-env` to manager our hosts.

The ansible-playbook `Basic-env` is doing the the basic environment setup(yum, generate keys, security tasks) and register the services.

The ansible-playbook `Upgrade-env` is doing the non-disruptive Upgrade(NDU) for the software and configuration.

We will dynamic put new hosts into inventory, and run `Basic-env` each 10 mins.

---

**Question**: Is possible to let ansible skip execute the tasks which in `Basic-env` at old hosts and only run them in new hosts?

Note: We do not want to run `playbook` for each new hosts separately, instead run run `Basic-env` each 10 mins for all hosts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply check for something on the host. Let's say your playbook generates the file `/foo/bar`. Then at the beginning of your playbook/role have a task like this:

```
- stat:
    path: /foo/bar
  register: check
```

Then for any task which you do not want to process you can apply a condition like this:

```
when: not p.stat.exists
```

Another (and maybe cleaner) solution is to use [local facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d). At the very end of your playbook create a file `/etc/ansible/facts.d/setup_complete.fact` with the content:

```
{"setup_complete": "true"}
```

When Ansible runs the next time, the fact `ansible_local.setup_complete` will be available. Then your condition could look like

```
when: "setup_complete" not in ansible_local
```