# How can I speedup ansible by not running entire sections too often?

Tags: ansible

Assume that a normal deployment script does a lot of things and many of them are related to preparing the OS itself.

These tasks are taking a LOT of time to run even if there is nothing new to do and I want to prevent running them more often than, let's say once a day.

I know that I can use tags to filter what I am running but that's not the point: I need to make ansible aware that these "sections" executed successfully one hour ago and due to this, it would skip the entire block now.

I was expecting that caching of facts was supposed to do this but somehow I wasnt able to see any read case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to let Ansible to skip run tasks on a host when its already configured?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592565/how-to-let-ansible-to-skip-run-tasks-on-a-host-when-its-already-configured)

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out how to determine what "executed successfully" means.  Is is just that a given playbook ran to completion?  Certain roles ran to completion?  Certain indicators exist that allow you determine success?

As you mention, I don't think fact caching is going to help you here unless you want to introduce custom facts into each host (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d)

I typically come up with a set of variables/facts  that indicate a role has already been run.  Sometimes this involves making shell calls and registering vars, looking  at gathered facts and determining if certain files exist.  My typical pattern for a role looks something like this

**roles/my_role/main.yml**

```
- name: load facts
  include: facts.yml

- name: run config tasks if needed
  include: config.yml
  when: fact_var1 and fact_vars2 and inv_var1 and reg_var1
```

You could also dynamically write a yaml variable file that get's included in your playbooks and contains variables about the configured state of your environment.  This is a more global option and doesn't really work if you need to look at the configured status of individual machines.  An extension of this would be to write status variables to host_vars or group_vars inventory variable files.  These would get loaded automatically on a host by host basis.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, fact caching only caches [host based facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts) such as those created by the [`setup`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/setup_module.html) module so wouldn't allow you to use [`set_fact`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/set_fact_module.html) to register a fact that, for example, a role had been completed and then conditionally check for that at the start of the role.

Instead you might want to consider using Ansible with another product to orchestrate it in a more complex fashion.